# List all filenames with complete path and size in specified path with subdirs

Tags: bash

What command will give me list of all files in dir (include subfolders) with complete path and file size?

The closest I can go is with:

```
ls -alR /test | grep ^- | awk '{print $5 "\t " $9}'
```

Wanted result (size can be on right side too):

```
123     /test/fileA
4534    /test/fileB.sh
3456    /test/fileC.py
123     /test/log/mon.txt
4534    /test/log/tue.txt
3243456 /test/man/manual.odt
```

Comment: Did you already tried something?  Did you have a look at `man find`? Search for *format* !!

Comment: @RachidK. Correct, but `man bash`, `man ls` could be used too!  As question stand for *`files`*, I think most appropriated tool is `find`, with `-type f` and a small `-printf` syntax.

Comment: @F.Hauri : du with -a answers the pb as well.

Comment: @RachidK. `du -a` report `directories` too!  If you want files only, correct tool is `find` with `-type f`.

Comment: @RachidK. But regarding whole question, correct tool is `man`!! ;-)

Comment: Have you tried ```ls -lsh /test/*```?

Comment: I forget to use find. And try to get output from ls with partial sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution below, with explanations following

```
kalou@shinwey:~$ find /etc/lynx /etc/pulse -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n"  | head

162929  /etc/lynx/lynx.cfg
3581    /etc/lynx/lynx.lss
116     /etc/pulse/client.conf.d/00-disable-autospawn.conf
4933    /etc/pulse/default.pa
2078    /etc/pulse/system.pa
2374    /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
1201    /etc/pulse/client.conf
```

As you can see,

`find` accepts a list of directories as input to look for files. Looking for files is achieved using the `-type f` option. You may customize find output using `-printf` (`man printf` might help as well)

By the way: when you ask questions here, please show that you have worked to solve the issue, and what failed.

Comment: Will try to be more precise next time. Inded I try with ls command and closest I can get was: ls -alR /test | grep ^- |  awk '{print $5 "\t " $9}'

Comment: just wondering why | head?? At least output seems same with or without

Comment: ha sorry | head is not required, was here for my personnal tests before posting. It's used to limit the results to the fist 10 lines found